# C++ pThread Mutex lock in a for loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, race-condition

I understand how the Mutex lock and unlocking works in c++ but I am slightly confused about the following.

In my program am doing a video streaming in real time which is by running a for loop. Next frames from the video steams are passed into a function to perform KMeans of 3 clusters. The kmean routine is running on a separate thread off the main thread. Kmeans takes 20-30 seconds to perform clustering.

To avoid changes to the variable in the kMeans algorithm, i used Mutex to lock and unlock the resource to avoid conflicting as shown in the function below.

//do Kmeans function

```
void *do_Kmeans(void * arg){
pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex); //Mutex defined as global variable
myMeans *eMax = new myMeans(); //! Kmeans class
eMax->setImage(*source); //! Source image from the real time video str
eMax->doImageClustering(); //Perform Kmeans
pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex);

//return all the elements
}
```

Now the above function works well and there is not problem at all. But my question is just on the confusion about mutex.

The video stream at 30fps will run the for loop in main 30times a second but in each of 20-30 seconds than only Kmeans is done. So whats happens to the remaining time when the frames are passed to the function. I think it is discarded since the Mutex lock is locking the resource at the time. I wonder if this is true? Can I get some clear explanation on the Mutex as notes seems bit hard to understand.

Also what if I want to process all the consecutive  frames than I will have to create a stack and keep the frames in a stack but I am afraid the stack will grow exponentially and my memory will be flooded in a moment.

Comment: Never call a destructor like that unless you're writing a memory allocator. You need to use `delete`.

Comment: Unrelated: "...the above function works well and there is not problem at all." - You're *sure* about that? You should also be questioning the memory leak you're incurring and the inappropriate manual-firing of the object destructor. `eMax` shouldn't be dynamic in this code at all. It should be automatic.

Comment: sorry i was testing the performance just writing and i forgot to erase the destructor and I didnt notice that while writing here. Besides can you explain what you meant by eMax shouldn't be dynamic in this code at all. It should be automatic.

Comment: Is it your intent that the `eMax` object should live beyond the scope of this function? If yes, and its being cleaned up somewhere else, then its ok dynamic. Otherwise it should be `myMeans eMax; eMax.setImage(...); etc..`;

Comment: Why do you lock on &Mutex and the unlock on &gmmMutex?

Comment: sorry that was typing mistake. I will edit it now. It is just Mutex.

Comment: @WhozCraig ok i see what you meant there. Actually the function will be live till the program runs. B

Comment: You're not *launching* this thread with each kmeans calculation you need, are you ?

Comment: My intension is to launch the kmeans function whenever the function becomes ready.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have no idea what that means. This is a thread proc. It is launched with a `pthread_create` call (or a `std::thread` construction). Is it your intention to invoke `pthread_create` with each kmeans you need to calculate? Or rather, is it your *hope* that you can have a thread *already* running, waiting for a source buffer on which to perform your kmeans crunching, at which point it is "awoken" and performs the requested work, then returns to idle until the next request?

Comment: i want the thread to be running and wait for the data.

Comment: Ok the code you've posted isn't anywhere close to that.  The code posted looks more like a one-shot worker thread launch that expires once done. The setup you seem to want is considerably more elaborate than that. I suggest a review of pthread usage in general, or the `std::thread` support library with C++11. For pthreads, [this site is pretty good](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html#SYNCHRONIZATION).

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you for your time and create website for tutorial. I  will go over them again. Cheers